# Why am I receiving an error: 'No match for operator >> in std'?

Tags: c++, arrays

I can't seem to understand why I am receiving an error for the code below. I have tried rewriting the code and it doesn't seem to correct the problem. It should not be giving me an error that I can see.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()

{
    int month[12] = {0, 31, 60, 91, 121, 152, 182, 213, 243, 274, 305, 335};
    int  year, dayNumber, day;

    cout<< "Please enter the month, by numerical value:";
    cin >> month;
    cout<<"Please enter the day, by numerical value:";
    cin >> day;
    cout<<"Please enter the year, by numerical value:";
    cin >> year;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`month` is an array, so it doesn't support syntax like `cin >> month;`

Based on the logic, I think you need a different variable for month number, from 1 to 12.

```
int month_start_days[12] = {0, 31, 60, 91, 121, 152, 182, 213, 243, 274, 305, 335};
int  year, dayNumber, day, month;

cout<< "Please enter the month, by numerical value:";
cin >> month;
```

Comment: You will have to subtract 1 from month when you access month_start_days, because array indexing in C starts at 0.

Comment: @user2654818 what do you mean? Why subtract 1 when it starts at 0?

Comment: @user2654818 Either input numbers from 0 to 11, or subtract 1 when indexing, it's up to the OP.

Comment: @AlexJonMartinWalter: Because normal people aren't going to say that January is month zero.

Answer (score 4):

Operator `>>` is not overloaded for arrays.

```
int month_index;
cin >> month_index;
```

Answer (score 2):

This fails because month is an array

```
cin >> month;
```

Answer (score 2):

`cin >> month;`

is causing the error , you can't input array like that.

What you probably want is to take `month` input using a separate varaiable.

Answer (score 2):

This works as a simple example (only if you desire to modify an array):

```
std::cin >> month[0]; // first element
```

Specifically, you can only access a certain index in range in this state.

Comment: This worked! Thank you, I did not know I needed to overload for arrays.

Comment: @AlexJonMartinWalter: Surely, you don't want to modify the array? It looks more like you want to input a separate variable, then use that array for some kind of month-related calculation with it.

Comment: @MM.: Yes, I know.  I was going for the simpler example in this case.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I don't want to modify the array I simply want to use the stored value in the calculations. For month 1 you don't add but for month 2 you would add 31 so that the dayNumber is correct and so on and so forth for the rest of the months.

Comment: @AlexJonMartinWalter: That's what I thought. So don't follow the advice in this answer, which is telling you to overwrite the first element of the array with the input. Instead, declare another variable for the input (as other answers describe).